# How to access the web page using specific port?

Tags: linux, iptables, apache-2.4, port, port-forwarding

I created two directories for storing the website on the web server

```
/web
/web/admin
```

Assume that my website domain is `http://www.domain.com/` and I would like to using the port 8080 for the admin page.

How can I restrict the url `http://www.domain.com:8080` point to `/web/admin` and the `http://www.domain.com:80` still point to `/web`?

I know most of web control panel doing like that. Can anyone guide me how I can do this?

Here is my environment: `Linux CentOS 7.0, Apache/2.4.6`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it manually, edit the file nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

and change your virtual host configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# [ Server Domain ]
ServerName www.domain.com
# [ Server Root ]
DocumentRoot /web/
# [ Prevent direct access to admin]
Redirect 301 /admin/ http://www.domain.com:8080
</VirtualHost >

Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
# [ Server Domain ]
ServerName www.domain.com
# [ Server Root ]
DocumentRoot /web/admin/
</VirtualHost >
```

By the way `sites-enabled/000-default.conf` is a symbolic link of `sites-available/000-default.conf`

You should set your web site and admin site in two separate folder to have two clean virtual host, without protecting direct access with a redirect

You can set listening port in /etc/apache2/ports.conf instead of your website configuration if you want

Comment: You'll also want to change the entries in the ports.conf file, which configures where Apache is listening. Look for the "Listen" directive.

Comment: I edited the post, to add this information

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you had already placed a "Listen" directive in the web site configuration.

Comment: I didn't you corrected me :P